# Collect Asterisk cdr records by http post

Tags: http, url, voip, asterisk, cdr

I'm using Asterisk and want to collect cdr records. I searched for a while, and found that there are already modules which we can use to collect cdr records into CSV files or MySQL.

I'm wondering that whether there is already a module which let me collect cdr records by http post. So that when a call finished, Asterisk will post cdr records to a predefined URL.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: There was such module, but it was removed due nobody use it. You can ask someone with c/c++ skill to do such module, it is simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know such a module, but you could execute an Application on Hangup.

You could use the function `${CURL(url[,post-data])}`:

```
exten => h,n,Set(result=${CURL(http://SERVER/cdr.php?\
             cdranswer=${CDR(answer)}&exten=${EXTEN}&cidnum=${CALLERID(num)})}) 
exten => h,n,Noop(${result})
```

Another Approach is to execute a Script on Hangup:

```
exten => h,n,System('php -f /opt/scripts/cdr.php \
                        ${CallerID(num)} ${EXTEN} "${CDR(answer)}" ${EPOCH}');
```

Maybe you could also use ${CDR(billsec)}.

Comment: Note, by default curl have issues with more then 10 connections same time. Changable in source files.

Comment: It looks like a good solution, but I don't know much about extension script. So at last I read the source code of cdr by mysql, and make a module by myself to do the task. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a CRON job to run a Ruby or PHP script every few minutes to extract and HTTP POST all of the CDRs since the last time the script was run.  I've done that for a customer and it works reasonably well.

That said, what I've found is that if I need to have CDRs accessible "off machine", the easiest way to do it over the long haul is set up MySQL replication;  write the CDRs to the PBX machine, read them from the replicated copy on the reports machine.  It's a bit more set-up intensive at the beginning, but makes everything else a heck of a lot easier later on.